# How to manage Grease Pencil Brushes in Blender 2.80?

Tags: grease-pencil

I got these textured brushes for Grease Pencil by Daniel Martinez: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpY-WVQUxYw

I can import in the brushes from the file using append method shown in the last video on this page: https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5ccfe64353b85e279cf72acd

After, importing the brushes I can work with all the brushes imported. But, as soon as we quit the application and open the file again we only get the brush that was used on the selected 2d layer.

**Is there a way to manage the brushes in Blender 2.80. ?**

It would be great to have library panel where we can import and export the custom brushes at the application level and not the file level.

*Note: I am using Blender 2.80 on Linux mint installed using snap packages.*