# How to remain the appended Brushes in grease pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil, draw-mode

The appended brush pack disappeared and reset to the default brushes every time I restart Blender. Is there a way to remain the appended Brushes in grease pencil(?)

Similar Question haven't been solved:
[How to manage Grease Pencil Brushes in Blender 2.80?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157527/how-to-manage-grease-pencil-brushes-in-blender-2-80)

The brush pack are appended and download from https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5f235cc297f8815e74ffb90b
https://cloud.blender.org/p/gallery/5ccfe64353b85e279cf72acd.

Answer (score 1):

After appending, select the brush, open the *Active Tool and Workspace Settings* menu on the right and next to the brush there is this shield icon.

When you hover your mouse over it it displays:

> *Fake user. Save this data-block even if it has no users.*

Make sure to click that so it's blue, and to do this to every different brush you want to use next time, or else Blender sees them as unused and doesn't bother saving them.

[image: Where to find the shield icon]

Comment: The shield icon is checked but all the appended brush disappeared after relaunched.
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/HSh4hzw" data-context="false" ><a href="//imgur.com/a/HSh4hzw"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: Not sure why this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the brushes to be available every time you open new project?
Then open a new project, append the brushes, do the shield thing above for each brush and from the top-left menu select File>Defaults>Save Startup File. This way every time you open new project it starts from that exact point. Hopefully this one fixes your problem!
[image: where to find it]

Comment: Although the the startup file is saved according to your guide, the appended brush turned in to grey square icons that are not able to be used.
https://imgur.com/rFBi7XX